# Seal the office ziplocks Bobby

Tags: riddle

My favorite number is 1, use it to find me.

It really is my fav number, add it to find me.

BTW, I used to sing, lot of people still know me - yes you got it right, I'm writing this from cali ! Love.

**Hint 1:**

> Use the title to find me

**Hint 2:**

> The artist name must be derived from the title, one of his song's title is in the post

Comment: Is the fav short for favorite or may it also be for something like favela club (idk if they have numbers)?

Comment: @Gimli short of favorite

Comment: I won't be able to solve this because the title sounds like Hank from King of the Hill XD can't stop thinking/saying it in that manner. RIP

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea

> How to use the title to find you.

That said, I can’t shake the feeling that

> The answer is **Three Dog Night**.

My favorite number is 1, use it to find me.

> The song One (One is the loneliest number...) was sung by Three Dog Night

It really is my fav number, add it to find me.

> If you add it a couple times, you get three, as in Three Dog Night

BTW, I used to sing, lot of people still know me

> They’re a pretty famous band that most people still know

- yes you got it right, I'm writing this from cali ! Love.

  > Three Dog Night was formed in Los Angeles, California

Comment: Nice try ! You really need to use the title to find me tho :p